Whitney’s first embedding theorem, embedding as closed subsets
The Whitney embedding theorem that I knew was from the Lee's book (Theorem 6.15: Every smooth n-manifold with
or without boundary admits a proper smooth embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$).
However, in several places like here or this answer I came across a version which claim every n-dimensional
differentiable manifold can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ as a closed subset.
I am having a hard time understanding the closed subset part intuitively. Consider for example an open interval like $(0,1)$ or an open disk in  $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ as smooth manifolds, how is it possible to embed them as closed subsets in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{5}$, receptively?

The open interval is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$, and this you surely know how to embed as a closed subset. Similarly for the open disk.
